# Is it possible to define any size array in a C function call?

Tags: arrays, c, memory, stack

does the below code is safe to use? somehow I think this not right way to do. I know a better way is malloc(), realloc(). But I want to understand where this code posses most risk. As compiler does not know the allocation size, how the stack size will be defined ?

```
int array_call(int k)

{
   int temp[k];
   int = 0;
   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0;i<k;i++)
       {
         temp[i]=i;
       }
    return k;

}

int main()
{

int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
n=array_call(n);

}
```

Comment: They are called [Variable Length Array](https://www.google.com/search?q=variable+length+array) or VLA, for short

Comment: [Variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are an optional feature of the ISO C standard and therefore may not work on certain compilers.

Comment: Would you like to show code which compiles without errors?

Comment: Have you tried it with n= 10000000?

Comment: If the user enters a very large number in `stdin`, then your program is likely to crash due to a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

Comment: That code also permits negative numbers as input. Careful with that…

Comment: @pmg ,Andreas Wenzel thanks I was not aware of this feature in C.

As stark pointed out it is bound to fail for large n. Even malloc() is also bound to fail for a very large allocation request. But it will return a null pointer. But how variable-length array feature handled in the compiler? Is there a way to safely use it. Can anyone explain these questions?

Comment: No, there is no way to use VLA safely. Other than in toy programs, I'd prefer `malloc()` and friends ... for some reason it was changed from required in C99 to [optional in C11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8.3)

Comment: you should avoid using VLAs with **automatic** storage expect toy programs or cases when you are absolutely sure that size is small enough. Use dynamic storage (`malloc` and friends). VLAs are dedicated for handling multidimension arrays where this feature really shines.

Comment: @pmg, to be more precise, it is not possible to handle **automatic** VLAs safely. However this feature is really useful for handling multidimensional arrays. There was even a proposal for C23 to limit `__STDC_NO_VLA__` to disallowing only *automatic* VLAs but requiring support for other Variably Modified types. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2778.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the below code is safe to use?

No.

> somehow I think this not right way
> to do. I know a better way is malloc(), realloc(). But I want to
> understand where this code posses most risk.

Risk #1: the feature you are relying upon, variable-length arrays, is optional in C11 and later, and absent (at least not standardized) in C90.  Only in C99 is it both standard and mandatory.  Many C implementations you will meet implement it, but there are notable ones that do not.  Your code will not compile at all on the latter.

Risk #2: C does not specify how automatic VLAs are implemented, but it is common for them to be allocated on the stack.  In such implementations it is relatively easy to cause the program to fail with a stack overflow by providing too large a value of `n`.  There is usually (much) more space available for dynamic allocation with `malloc()` &co., but even if there weren't, you can at least detect and recover from a `malloc()` failure.  Similar applies to the possibility that `n` is given as a negative number.

Risk #3: you are using unvalidated user input in a sensitive way.  This is a major failing of secure programming protocol.

> As compiler does not know
> the allocation size, how the stack size will be defined ?

You're assuming that there is a stack, and that that's where the VLA will go.  Neither is guaranteed.  Nor is there a requirement for a particular behavior in those implementations where both of those assumptions hold.  In practice, however, the compiler is reasonably likely to allocate VLA members at the top of the stack, above non-VLA members, and simply to adjust the stack pointer appropriately for the value of `n`.  It's a little trickier if there are multiple VLAs, but totally doable.  This is among the least of the problems involved.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further on :
"You're assuming that there is a stack and that that's where the VLA will go. Neither is guaranteed. Nor is there a requirement for a particular behavior in those implementations where both of those assumptions hold."
In what cases, there will be no stack-allocated? I want to understand this in a more detailed manner.

Comment: @SourodeepBasu, there's not much more to say.  The call stack is an implementation concept, not a C-language concept.  It is possible to create a conforming C implementation that does not rely on a call stack.  It is even more possible and plausible among implementations for commodity hardware for there to be a call stack, but VLAs not to be allocated there.  None of that is really driven by the C source code involved

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a variable-length array (VLA), where the array size isn't known until runtime.  This feature was introduced in the 1999 revision of the language, but was made optional in the 2011 revision.

So, the first risk is that VLAs are not universally supported - this code may not compile on some platforms.  On C2011 and later, you'll want to check if the `__STDC_NO_VLA__` feature macro has been defined before trying to use them, something like

```
#if defined( __STDC_NO_VLA__ )
  int *temp = malloc( sizeof *temp * k );
#else
  int temp[k]; 
#endif

/** do stuff with temp **/

#if defined( __STDC_NO_VLA__ )
  free( temp );
```

The second main risk is that VLAs cannot be arbitrarily large - many (if not most) implementations try to allocate VLA space from the stack, and stack space tends to be limited.  If `k` is too large<sup>1</sup> you will likely get some kind of unrecoverable runtime error.

VLAs may not be declared at file scope or with the `static` keyword, nor may they be members of `struct` or `union` types.

---

1. The exact value of "too large" depends on the platform, compiler, source code, etc.

Comment: Also VLAs cannot be initialized (C11 6.7.9p3)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a compiler that doesn't support VLAs ([Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s), you might just have that function allocate, and return, an array with the given size.

```
int *NewInitedArrayWithCount( unsigned int arrayCount )
{
   int *array = (int *) malloc( arrayCount * sizeof( int ));
   if ( array != NULL )
   {
      for ( int i = 0; i<arrayCount; i++ )
       {
            array[i] = (int) i;
       }
   }
   return array;
}

int main()
{
   unsigned int arrayCount;
   scanf( "%u", &arrayCount );
   int *array = NewInitedArrayWithCount( arrayCount );

   // Do stuff

   if ( array != NULL )
      free( array );
   return 0;
}
```